# Building and Using Node.js' C(++) Core Dependencies in Node.js

Tags: c++, node.js

I am trying to use Node.js' C/C++ code to define a function, `getInternalBinding`, in my Node.js project. The C++ source code can be found in `node/src/`, and I need to get the function from `node_binding.cc`. Here is the DownGit link to download the entire C++ src code: [downgit](https://downgit.github.io/#/home?url=https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/aabbf3011b59c6412508086e7a831c02cf3a21aa/src). Can I use this code in my Node.js project? I tried to reference it from my index.js like: `const getInternalBinding = require('./node_binding.cc')` but i get a SyntaxError:

```
#include "node_binding.h"
^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Is there any way to include this file easily? Thanks in advance!